# isomorphism between $\mathbb H P^1$ and $S^4$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, quaternions

Let $G\subset \mathbb H$ be the Lie groups of unit quaternions that acts from the right on $S^7:=\{(q_1,q_2)\in \mathbb H^2: |q_1|^2+|q_2|^2=1\}$. If $S^4:=\{(q,x)\in \mathbb H\oplus \mathbb R: |q|^2+x^2=1\}$, I want to prove that the map $f:S^7/G\to S^4$ defined by
$$f([q_1,q_2]):=(2q_1\overline{q_2}, |q_1|^2-|q_2|^2)$$
is a diffeomorphism. Proving that it's well defined is trivial but the bijectivity is already tricky. I tried to find the inverse but i can't find it.
Another way is through $\mathbb H P^1$: It's not difficult to prove that $S^7/G\cong \mathbb H P^1$ but i can't prove that $\mathbb H P^1\cong S^4$.

Any help?

Comment: It's the same for the quaternionic case as for the complex case (just with more real dimensions). The map $[q_1,q_2]\mapsto \frac{q_1\overline q_2}{|q_2|^2}$ takes $\mathbb{H}P^1=S^7/G$ onto the one-point compactification $S^{\mathbb{H}}\cong S^4$. The formula you write down is exactly the steroegraphic projection realising this last homeomorphism. Finally just check that the resulting composition is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: How do we know that the map to $S^\mathbb{H}$ is a diffeomorphism?

Comment: It's the [sterographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection). It's well-known that this is a homeomorphism. I'm not claiming that its a difeomorphism because I wouldn't normally put an explicit smooth structure on the one-point compactification. What I am claiming, is that if you take the composite of the two maps I wrote (each of which is a homeorphism, so one-to-one and onto), then you get the map $f$, and can check directly that it is smooth.

Comment: Have you shown that $f$ is bijective or is that point open, too?